# rtbkit create add exchange that can send bid via UI

Tags: rtbkit

How to create an add exchange for POC for RTBKIT.I want to create end to end program such that there is UI which send a parameter height and width and that request goes to rtbkit and then response will send a URL and that imag will be displayed on UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performing this,we need an exchange that can send request to rtbkit running at your system.

> http://integration.rubiconproject.com/rtb/request

The solution will be create a web application that will call this add exchange via selenium or HttpClient and fill the RTB Endpoint.This will call the rtbkit instance running at your system and in response you will get image of the bidding agent that won during this process and we will show that image at our website.